# IntegrityError at /normalsignup/ NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_user.usertype

Tags: python, sql, django

I have seen that there are other people having this issue as well as me, but having tried all of these solutions none of them appears to be helping. I keep getting an error saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ethan/mysite/polls/views.py", line 32, in normalsignup
    form.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 113, in save
    user.save()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1107, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_user.usertype
```

I understand that the issue is something to do with one of the fields, but have no idea what, or how to even start to try and fix it. I have copied in the relevant files that I think are necessary to fix this and would really appreciate any help that I can get given for this.

Here are my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from polls.forms import NormalSignUpForm, VenueSignUpForm, BLSignUpForm, BMSignUpForm, ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from polls.models import User


user = get_user_model()


def normalsignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NormalSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = NormalSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'normalsignup.html', {'form': form})  

class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']

        args = {'form' : form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    usertype = models.IntegerField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

and my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from polls.models import Post

User = get_user_model()

class NormalSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    usertype = 1

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

I would massively appreciate anyone and any time spent on this as I have been looking for a solution to this issue for quite some time now and have come to no way of fixing it. Thank you again for any that help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usertype = models.IntegerField()` - is a not null field.

The problem here is the `usertype` that you are setting in the class `NormalSignUpForm` is not picked up while form submission, so the violation occurs. While saving the user instance you can do something like:

```
def normalsignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NormalSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.usertype = 1
            form.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=raw_password)
            .......
```

Comment: This answer was missing `form.save()`. I've edited the answer so that it now calls save with `commit=False`, sets the usertype, then saves the user.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to save the form as you are logging the user in

so use this instead

```
def normalsignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NormalSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form= form.save(commit=False)
            form.usertype = 1
            form.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = NormalSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'normalsignup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: After this point, I get another error that says: AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'. I checked on SO and it caused the same error as the one above. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error as before with your correction